# How to search contents of OneNote notebooks on SkyDrive web interface

Tags: onedrive, onenote

Is there a way, in the SkyDrive web interface, to make it search the contents of OneNote pages/notebooks?

Here's a OneNote page I creates in July 2011. I've marked in the red the terms I'll search for, just as example words.

[image: screenshot on OneNote web app - with words Agh and tables highlighted]

And here are two attempts at searching for words in that page:

[image: Failed search for Agh]

[image: Failed search for tables]

I see that the text in the "Search results" page says "Recent changes may take a few minutes to be reflected" - but since the page was created in July 2011, I'm fairly confident that's not the issue.

Search of Word docs in SkyDrive works fine.

The OneNote file is definitely in "OneNote 2010 notebook format", so I don't believe it's a formatting issue.

**Is there anything I can do to make the SkyDrive web interface search OneNote docs contained there? Or is this just unsupported functionality?**